# Blank page when trying to download file

Tags: php, apache

I’m trying to force-download a file once the user clicks a link. When the link is clicked, a zip file is created on the fly and is downloaded on the user’s machine. My code works when run on localhost but displays a blank page when run from the server.

This is the link that downloads the file:

```
<a href="downloadfile.php"> Download </a>
```

And this is the downloadfile.php:

```
<?php

        $file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
        $zip->addFromString('test.txt', "this is a test file");
        $zip->close();

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testfile.zip" ');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        unlink($file);
        exit();
?>
```

Comment: What is status code of your server response?

Comment: Have you checked if the code is executed on the server and there is not a redirect problem for instance?

Comment: If you are in production I suppose your php.ini is different from your local. I guess an error has been throw (blank page). You should have a look to your apache logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have ziparchive enabled on your production server.

Also change this header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

To this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
```

You should use the right headers. I tested this on my local computer and it works.

Comment: I can't find "zip" when I run phpinfo. You think this is the issue?

Comment: Yes, what is your php version and the OS you use?

Comment: It is 5.1.6. I use macOS. Do you know of any workaround? I cannot update server to a newest version at this point

Answer (score 0):

I think there is any other issue because your script is working on my server try to add this line at top of your script page

```
ob_start();
```